# Load in CodeBuild environment variables from a file that's not checked into source control

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have an environment file that I use locally but that I don't have checked into source control. It looks similar to this:

**env.ts**

```
const config = {
  prod: {
    serviceA: {
      varA: 'xyz',
      varB: 'xyz',
      varC: 'xyz',
      varD: 'xyz',
    },
    serviceB: {
      varA: 'xyz',
      varB: 'xyz',
      varC: 'xyz',
      varD: 'xyz',
    },
  },
  test: {
    serviceA: {
      varA: 'xyz',
      varB: 'xyz',
      varC: 'xyz',
      varD: 'xyz',
    },
    serviceB: {
      varA: 'xyz',
      varB: 'xyz',
      varC: 'xyz',
      varD: 'xyz',
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

Using Webpack, I can load in the appropriate environment variables for a particular service when building locally. A module can access these environment variables like this:

```
import config from '@env';

  const {
    varA,
    varB,
    varC,
    varD,
  } = config[process.env.NODE_ENV].serviceA;
```

I have this project set up with an AWS CodePipeline and CodeBuild, and I realized that tests and building won't work because my **env.ts** file is not checked into source control because it contains sensitive credentials.

I can add environment variables inside the CodePipeline / CodeBuild consoles, but I don't think this will work since the code is referencing a file called env.ts that's not checked into source control.

Is it possible to maybe have this **env.ts** kept in something like S3 and then have it pulled into the pipeline to be used in the cloud during builds? Maybe I could load this file somehow in the buildspec? Here is my current buildspec for reference:

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo installing packages...
      - npm install --global yarn
      - yarn install
      # <-- load in env.ts file here somehow?
  build:
    commands:
      - echo running tests...
      - yarn jest
      - echo building...
      - yarn build

artifacts:
  files:
    - $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/dist/prod/*
```

Comment: You could use s3, dynamodb, secret manager or really any AWS service that can hold strings to achieve this. But for your case, s3 sounds good. Just use your codebuild stage to launch a shell script then execute cli commands to retrieve your file into directory. Otherwise you could have an empty shell config file  and import the string values into the file from secret manager during build. Etc

Comment: @pkarfs thanks for this. As I was typing this question, I started thinking that it could be possible for the buildspec to pull the file from a number of different places, so I wasn't sure if S3 would be the best thing to use for this. Gonna try this with S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code build already provides environment variables setup for this purpose.
Or you can use S3 private bucket to store the config files and pull the files at runtime using AWS S3 cli commands. Just make sure codebuild has been given necessary permission to pull the config files from s3 during the build. 
If you are using codebuild environment variables you can use parameter store to store your sensitive information and access in the buildspecyml by adding "$" in front of the environmentvariable you added to codebuild